# Can't use Post.slug with Jekyll on Github Pages

Tags: jekyll

I can get a post's slug using Post.slug when I build and serve Jekyll locally (using latest version of Jekyll), but when I push to Github, the value is no longer accessible. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but it's worth noting that Github Pages does not use the latest version of Jekyll. There is a github-pages gem that you can include locally to make sure you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: GitHub uses Jekyll 2.4 which should give you something when referencing slug on a post object ( https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/v2.4.0/lib/jekyll/tags/post_url.rb ). Are you just getting a blank string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slug` for post is what I introduced into Jekyll 3.0.1 for uncased slugified title of posts (see [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/4100)). It doesn't exist in any version prior to 3.0.1. Just like others mentioned above, GitHub hasn't adopted the latest version of Jekyll.

Comment: I guess I just assumed Github always would be up to date. Didn't realize that was a new-ish feature. Thanks!